# How to configure lib path for apache utilities?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I juste installed `apxs` bin with the `httpd24-httpd-devel-2.4.6-16.el6.x86_64` package.

I need it to compile PHP with Apache module.

When I launch the command  `apxs --help` I get the following error:

```
cannot open /httpd/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/bin/apxs line 214
```

I locate this file into `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/build/`, should I add this folder to my PATH or is there a way to tell Apache to look at this directory?

Comment: This may be a problem with the way that it was packaged. You should contact your Red Hat rep to open a support case.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem with SCL package httpd24-httpd-devel. There was already bug for standard CentOS/RedHat rpm which was fixed.

Since apxs is a perl script if you take a look inside it, this is the responsible code:

```
my $libdir = `pkg-config --variable=libdir apr-1`;
chomp $libdir;

my $installbuilddir = $libdir . "/httpd/build";
```

What you also can do is change the $installbuilddir variable to:

```
my $installbuilddir = '/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64' . "/httpd/build";
```

Just make sure you modify the httpd24 apxs, which is available at /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/bin/apxs, and not the orig one (/usr/sbin/apxs).

If you don't want to modify apxs, this quick fix would work also:

```
cd /
ln -s /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd .
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. The issue is `sudo make install` is destroying the path, and the wrong pkg-config gets called. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing `sudo make install` from inside a `scl enable httpd24 bash`? This resets $PATH to the default. You need to instead do:

```
sudo scl enable httpd24 perl516 'make install'
```